# Git: Workflow Dilemma - Rebase to a totally new branch?

Tags: git, github

We have a environment set up where we have 3 branches that auto deploy (Develop, Preprod, Master (Prod)). It's a multi site environment with multiple teams working on the repo.

Our goal is to be able to develop features and push them into 2 main workflows, one for testing, and then another for getting the code onto the production server via the preprod branch:
1. Push the changes into the develop branch for testing
2. Pushing into preprod branch to stage the production environment, then push the preprod environment up to production.

Our Issue:
We don't know which branch to start the feature request from.
If we start from develop, when we go to merge to Preprod (Workflow #2), it brings over every commit into the develop that isn't necessarily ready for Preprod. The same is the case when we start the feature off preprod.

The Goal:
**Ideally, we would like to be able to start the branch on develop, and merge it to the first workflow for testing. Then once it is ready to be merged into the 2nd workflow, do some kind of rebasing so the branch is now starting off preprod instead of develop. However, I don't think this is possible? Based on my understanding of rebasing, all you could do is simply move the branch is starting point further up the development branch, instead of moving the feature branch to now be starting off the preprod branch instead of the development. Is this possible? Or is there some other solution we could use to acheive the same effect that our team is overlooking?**

Answer (score 0):

Getting a git workflow right is hard. I would recommend using a workflow that already exists and is documented. That way it is more likely to work in real life scenarios and not have too many pitfalls.

[Atlassian documents a number of standard alternatives](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows).

Your concepts sound closest to the [gitflow workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow), so you could take a look at that. It contains many branch types: master, develop, releases, hotfixes and features.

Personally, I prefer the [feature branch workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow). It is actually simpler than gitflow, by having just master and feature branches, but it works best if you have careful code reviews (in pull requests) and automated tests with good coverage so that you can merge with confidence.